# How can I use the component of the other module in the current module?

Tags: angular

I have two modules. I need to show the component in the dialog box. But that component imports several components in it (more than 20). So If there was a single component I would have created in the common module. But this is more complicated. I have tried exporting the component from the other module. But that throws me an error because it's not declared in the entry components in this module.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    DocumentEditComponent,
    TestimonialLieuComponent,
    CommNetworkAddDialogComponent,
    GoalComponent,
    InterviewGuideComponent,
    JobCommunicationComponent,
    LearningComponent,
    MatchConfigComponent,
    PayDetailComponent,
    PerksAndBenefitsComponent,
    QuestionnaireComponent,
    VendorComponents,
    WorkRelatedComponent,
    ConfigurationComponent,
    BasicInfoComponent,
    AddDialogComponent,
    JdmDetailAddComponent,
    JdmDetailComponentComponent,
    InterviewGuideMapComponent,
    AdminOrgJdmComponent,
    AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent,
    OrgJdmAddComponent,
    OrgInterviewGuideComponent,
    OrgExperienceComponent,
    OrgCommNetworkComponent,
    OrgWorkRelatedComponent

],
exports: [
  TestimonialTemplateComponent,
  TestimonialComponent,
  AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent
],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TapCommonModule,
    RecruitmentConfigRoutingModule
],
entryComponents: [
    PhysicaldemandEditOrgComponent,
    InterviewProcessComponent,
    AssessmentsComponent,
    CareerPathComponent,
    DocumentComponent,
    ExperienceComponent,
    GoalComponent,
    InterviewGuideComponent,
    JobCommunicationComponent,
    LearningComponent,
    MatchConfigComponent,
    PayDetailComponent,
    PerksAndBenefitsComponent,
    QuestionnaireComponent,
    VendorComponents,
    WorkRelatedComponent,
    ConfigurationComponent,
    AddDialogComponent,
    JdmDetailAddComponent,
    InterviewGuideMapComponent,
    OrgJdmAddComponent,
    AssessmentOrgAddComponent,
    CareerPathOrgAddComponent,

],
providers: []
})
export class RecruitmentConfigModule {
}
```

And am calling the component in the dialog

```
openJD(): void {
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent, {
  width: '80%',
  data: this.jobDescription,
  height: '90%',
  disableClose: true
});
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

});
```

}

This throws me an error

> VM60232 JobRequisitionAddFormComponent.ngfactory.js:230 ERROR Error: No component factory found for AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Any other way to solve this. Please let me know

Comment: The error suggests what to do. "...Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?" AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent needs to be in the entry components.

Comment: @OneLunchMan Yes, I get it. But If I import all the components in both the modules which I am using. I think this is not the correct way. Might be there is a solution for this.

Comment: The comment (and answers below) do not say to import all of the components in both modules. This comment and the other answers are saying to add it to the entry components of the module it's declared in and exported from. Please refer to the documentation for more info. https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules#ngmodule-metadata

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent` into entryComponents in `@NgModule` like this:

Example :

```
entryComponents: [
    PhysicaldemandEditOrgComponent,
    InterviewProcessComponent,
    AssessmentsComponent,
    CareerPathComponent,
    DocumentComponent,
    ExperienceComponent,
    GoalComponent,
    InterviewGuideComponent,
    JobCommunicationComponent,
    LearningComponent,
    MatchConfigComponent,
    PayDetailComponent,
    PerksAndBenefitsComponent,
    QuestionnaireComponent,
    VendorComponents,
    WorkRelatedComponent,
    ConfigurationComponent,
    AddDialogComponent,
    JdmDetailAddComponent,
    InterviewGuideMapComponent,
    OrgJdmAddComponent,
    AssessmentOrgAddComponent,
    CareerPathOrgAddComponent,
    AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent //<-- here

],
```

Comment: The function am calling is in another module. So it wont cause any difference if i add in the other component.

Comment: If you get the problem am facing. It would be helpful if you suggest me any other way.

Comment: Then try to export all the components used in the child module to let the parent module use them. and please edit your code with both modules.

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add the AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent to the entryComponents array.
As the error says, it is not found there.
Since you load it dinamically, I think you have to tell Angular to load it imperatively.

```
...
entryComponents: [
    ...
    AdminOrgJdmDetailComponent 
],
...
```

You can find more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components).

Comment: I dont think you get the problem. There are two different modules. I am calling a dialog component in another module.

Comment: Have you tried including it both in the entryComponents and the exports array? The exports will allow you to use in the other module, the entryComponents will take care of the imperative loading.

Comment: If one I can import in the other module too. But there are many components used in that single component. So its throwing me an error for each component that is used.

Comment: I understand. Maybe there is another way, but I do not know it. The [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#entrycomponents-and-the-compiler) says that "For the ones (components) you don't reference, the tree shaker drops these components from the final code package". If those components are only dinamically rendered (as in a method call) they are probably being dropped if not explicitly included in the entryComponents array (and exports array since you're using them in other module).